# Wrong mouse cursor, bug or feature?

Tags: macos, mouse

New iMac, newest version of Mavericks. When using Apple apps (it seems like all of them) a curious bug or feature can be observed when selecting some text.

A simple way to exhibit is to slowly select some text in the Safari address bar using the mouse button. While continuing to hold down the mouse button, move the cursor out of the text field and release the button (make sure you have moved completely out of the field before releasing the button). The cursor will continue to appear as an "I", instead of changing to a pointer (or whatever it should be given what the mouse cursor is now over) as might be expected. You probably will have to do this twice in a row to get it to happen.

Curiously, the same behavior is not observed in some non-Apple apps, so perhaps this is actually considered a feature somehow. I can't see how it could possibly be a bug because it is so obvious.

So my questions are - does this happen on your Mac? Any idea if this is a bug or a feature?

Comment: I can confirm your findings.

Comment: To add, it remains as the select cursor type only in that line or even in a paragraph. As if it does not receives the EOL signal. As soon you move out of a single line or paragraph it is back to normal.

Comment: If it is a feature, I do not know what to do with it. For now I call it a Bug.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for confirming. I thought maybe it was to let you know you could still CMD-C copy the text or something. Seeing how it happens dozens of times by accident when I'm using the computer it's hard to imagine it not being stamped out as a bug. But it seems a bit too random to be intentional. I wonder if Yosemite beta is exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: Yeah, Yosemite has the same behaviour. I just managed to reproduce the problem on the latest beta

Comment: I hope we can all give feedback/bug reports for this to get it fixed finally!

Comment: Another way to see the bug is when you open the "Note" applicaton. Click in the page to insert text and then go out from the note, slowly with your mouse. The "I" cursor remains instead of the arrow. The bug is in mavericks and yes, in yosemite too. On every mac with 10.9 or 10.10, also the newest ones (I was in the apple stores to test it on newest mac!!!). And another bug (on the two latest osx) is the time (short but there is) to load the icons of the files/apps when you open a new window.

Comment: I tried 10.11 on new partition. Bug is still possible to reproduce, but it looks like they took steps to make it happen in less instances. Mail, for example, is a lot better.